# How to use "or" and "and" in the same cloudsearch query?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

How is possible to use "**or**" and "**and**" in the same query?

I have two queries that are working fine:

```
http://xxx.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/search?q=keyword&bq=(or field_1:'x' field_1:'y')


http://xxx.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/search?q=keyword&start=0&bq=(and field_3:'x' field_4:'True')
```

field_1 is a literal type.

The first one I am using "or" and the second "and" conditional. How can I put this both queries in one? I tried in several ways but am always getting some error from Amazon CloudSearch.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it. Here is the answer:

```
(and field_2:'x' field_3:'y' (or field_1:'w' field_1:'z' ))
```